# p:selectOneMenu will not print a value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Why is my code printing this instead of printing students names that are saved in a database?

Here is my code:

```
public class stdmanagedbean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        studentmn mani = new studentmn();
        students = mani.getStudentList();
    }

    public stdmanagedbean() {
    }

    private List<student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
```

The method that populates the list

```
public student populatestd(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    student st = new student();
    st.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    st.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    return st;
}
```

Here is my xhtml code

```
<body>
    <h:form>
       <p:outputLabel for="list" value="STUDENTS: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="list"  value="#{stdmanagedbean.students}" style="width:500px">

             <f:selectItems value="#{stdmanagedbean.students}"/>
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one of these" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />

             </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: how can i get that done and as u can see i am using a list of students

Comment: thank you sooooooooooooooo much  Billy Hope it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a var named "student" for example, then use `itemLabel="student.name"`, this will display the names of the students, and `itemValue="student"` is used to define the value of the selected item :

```
<f:selectItems var="student" value="#{stdmanagedbean.students}" itemLabel="#{student.name}" itemValue="#{student}"/>
```